# How well does the Recess! PHP Framework play with dojo.data?

Tags: php, rest, dojo, recess

I've been trying to find the perfect php framework for me that integrates with dojo smoothly.
I am trying to avoid creating my own framework and I don't want to use the Zend Framework since I don't like it and I have a choice since it's my project.
I really like the [Recess! framework](http://www.recessframework.org/). It looks easy to get started with a easy to develop with.
Has anyone had experience modifying it to generate dojo.data json format?
If not, how easy should it be to do so?

Thanks in advance,
Omer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new content negotiation features in Recess 0.2 (released yesterday), it should just be a matter of creating a json template in the view (index.json.php), and sending requests to /home/index.json

You should be able to return any json format you wish.

Hope that answers your question.